# Set different color theme when running in console

Tags: emacs, themes

I'm trying to set a different color theme when running in windows-server and in console (Cygwin). The problem is that if I try to set `custom-enabled-themes` or `custom-safe-themes` anywhere outside the `custom-set-variables` block, they don't seem to have any effect.

What gives? The manual is silent about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use programatically `load-theme` and/or `enable-theme` (at least in emacs 24.3).  This way you don't need to flag themes as safe (since you are supposed you know what you are doing), and you may use a `(if (display-graphic-p) ...)` to select your theme.

Answer (score 0):

EmacsWiki has a section on how to do that: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme#toc11.

It also has an explanation on what to do if you run emacs in daemon mode and want different themes for different frames (both console and GUI).